# How to add decorator support to react+typescript+mobx in codesandbox?

Tags: codesandbox

I want to be able to use mobx's `@observer` in my typescript code in a codesandbox. However I am getting this error:

/src/content.tsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled (6:1):

```
  4 | import { observer } from "mobx-react";
  5 | 
> 6 | @observer
    | ^
  7 | export class Particle extends React.Component {
```

I have already:

1) Added dependencies

[image]

2) Add a `.babelrc` file with these content

[image]

but I cannot get rid of the error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: nope ☹️ ........

Answer (score 0):

Add this to tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
 "experimentalDecorators": true
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File > Preference > Settings > Search "experimental"`

Then check `Javascript › Implicit Project Config: Experimental Decorators`